# How to convert datetime variable to string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert datetime variable to string in JavaScript?

Comment: What kind of datetime variable? JavaScript has no such data type, only a `Date` object.

Comment: i passed date object while rendering i got serialization problem in view page.i cant able to get correct date format.i got a result as /Date(1281067200000),but i want result as 8/6/2010?

Answer (score 4):

I've had a lot of success with [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). It took away a lot of pain.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what kind of DateTime variable you're talking about, so I'll assume you're talking about `Date`:

```
var stringVal = someDateVar.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var stringrepresentation = datetimevalue.toString();
```